# How to deploy Datadog into Databricks

Tags: databricks, datadog

How to deploy Datadog into Databricks and also i need logs display in Datadog dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Datadog has a Spark integration which involves cluster init scripts and environment variables. The [setup for Databricks](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/databricks/?tab=driveronly#pagetitle) is documented on this page. It logs these [metrics](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/spark/?tab=host#metrics) and these [service checks](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/spark/?tab=host#service-checks).